# didDeselectItemAtIndexPath is not working when reloadData is called

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

didDeselectItemAtIndexPath method is not firing when I tried to select. Please let me know if there is any setting wrong in my code.

I am trying to display ticked icon if the image is selected and if deselect then disappear the image.

Thank you for your help.

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.getMediaFilePath(self.mediaModels[indexPath.row].pathToMedia))
    if self.mediaModels[indexPath.row].isSelected {
        cell.imageTicked.hidden = false
        cell.selected = true
    } else {
        cell.imageTicked.hidden = true
        cell.selected = false
    }
    return cell

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    var cell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
    self.mediaModels[indexPath.row].isSelected  = true
    cell.selected = true
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    var cell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.mediaModels[indexPath.row].isSelected  = false
    cell.selected = false
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let cellSize = (collectionView.frame.width / 4) - 4

    return CGSizeMake(cellSize, cellSize)
}
```

Comment: does the `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` method ever work before you call `reloadData`?  and why are you reloading everything, anyways?  Just to pick up the ticked icon?  You already know which cell is being selected and de-selected, you can change the graphic in that cell without reloading everything.

Comment: yes it is working if i comment out reloadData() in didSelectItemAtIndexPath and didDeselectItemAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    var cell : CollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
    self.mediaModels[indexPath.row].isSelected  = true
    cell.selected = true
    cell.imageTicked.hidden = false
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    var cell : CollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.mediaModels[indexPath.row].isSelected  = false
    cell.selected = false
    cell.imageTicked.hidden = true
}
```

I get it to work without reloading the data. Just set the imageTicked hidden in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath and didDeselectItemAtIndexPath method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Use   cell.userInteractionEnabled=YES; in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.